# Adding Dependencies In C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sfml

In C# you can add references to DLLs to get functionality.

But in C++ you can add dependencies that are included automatically when you compile so you don't have to copy them automatically into the Debug/Release folders every time you make a new project.

Is this possible with C# projects?

The reason I ask is because I want to make a Template where the files I need are included automatically.

Answer (score 1):

On a file in Visual Studio, look at the properties for the "Copy To Output Directory" attribute.  If I understand your question, this may be what you want.  The output location is the "output path" setting specified in the project's build settings.

Comment: I agree. You can specify; create your own copy of a file OR use the original in its location

Comment: I want to include external DLLs in my output folder.

Comment: You can add the DLLs to the project as regular files and set them to copy to the output directory.  Or, you can copy them manually in a separate build target, but this is more involved.